# How to compare nested list and append not matches to new list in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, compare, comparison, nested-lists

```
I want to compare 2 nested list. compare index 1 of list 1 with list 2 index 1 and appedn list 1 , list 2 to the new list.  in python3
            l1 = [['a','bat','c'], ['a','doll','c']]
            l2 = [['a','flowers','c'],['a','god','c'],['a','bat','c']]              
            output = []
            for i in l1:
                for j in l2:
                        if i[1] != j[1]:
                            output.append(j)
                            
                break           
            print(output)           
            Expected Output:
            [['a','doll','c'] ,['a','flowers','c'],['a','god','c']
```

I want to compare 2 nested list. compare index 1 of list 1 with list 2 index 1 and appedn list 1 , list 2 to the new list.  in python3